# Download .php files using $_GET PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, download

Basically I have a website and I'm a new PHP developer but no matter how hard I try I can't get this crap to download.

What I've tried and what I want it to be like.

```
<?php
$var = (isset($_GET['dl']) && $_GET['dl'];
if($var == "flash"){
readfile('path/to/file');
}
elseif($var == "and so on){
die('you get the point');
}
?>
```

I know you have to include headers etc, but the main problem I run into with this sort of thing is when it downloads it downloads the page that you're on not the page i'm trying to get downloaded.

I'm trying to release some other things in php i've coded with notes etc inside the .php file but I can't seem to get the files to download properly.
All help is appreciated

Also the button will be like

```
<button onclick="location.href='download.php?dl=something'"/>
```

or I could use input.

if you know how to do this in javascript/jquery alone that would work!

EDIT: I'd also rather not have to add a new if/elseif statement every time i want to add a file to my download page. I know this is able to be done by defining a file type but I don't know exactly how. Kudos to anyone who helps :3

Answer (score 0):

to download a file in php all you need to do is set the headers...

try this

```
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/zip');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($var));
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($var));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($var);
            exit;
```

Comment: Yeah but whenever I put that in there once you visit just download.php it auto downloads the download.php pages html. Where should I place that?

Comment: then the $var must contain the path to the html page... you need to also consider where the php script is in the directory